# How to make Jquery UI timespinner increment hours/minutes based on highlighted section of the input?

Tags: jquery

I have an input for a file's duration for which i'm using timespinner's script.
I have this simple code:

HTML:

```
<input type="time" min="00:00:01" max="24:00:00" step="1" value="00:00:00" id="config-file-time">
```

JS:

```
$('#config-file-time').timespinner({
    format:'HH:mm:ss',
    step: 1,
});
```

On the UI, there are no +/- arrows, so you just use the keyboard's up/down arrows to increment the values, or you type them by hand. This is working fine.

The problem is the values only increment 1 second, even if i have the minutes section of the input selected (like the screenshot below).
[image: timespinner minutes field highlighted]

I've read all the documentation of timespinner and there doesn't seem to be any option for what i'm trying to achieve. I've thought of changing the increment based on the highlighted section of the input, but there is no option to configure different increments for the hours/minutes/seconds separately.

Does anyone have any solution? Even if it means using something different altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't select more precisely the value in the input. However, in addition to step you can add page in your options to change the value using the pageUp button like in this [example](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time).

But in your situation, I suggest you to use something like [jQuery Time Entry](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html). It will let your users change their time entry with different ways, even with the mousewheel.